# Azure Release Notes Wiki Markdown date

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, azure-devops-wiki

I am completely new to this so any help and explanation would be appreciated.
I have a created a template that will generate my release notes in our wiki. I am using the Generate Release Notes Markdown (crossplatform) extension by Richard Fennell.
In the template section of the extension, I use this short and simple template:

```
# {{releaseDetails.name}}
**Date** : {{releaseDetails.modifiedOn}}
**Build Number**: {{buildDetails.buildNumber}}
{{#forEach workItems}}
{{#if isFirst}}## Work Items{{/if}}
- **{{lookup this.fields 'System.WorkItemType'}}** #{{this.id}}
{{/forEach}}
```

The output is as follows:
Release-17
Date : Mon Dec 05 2022 18:19:37 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
Build Number: 20221026.4

Everything is good except I would like to change the date and time format to just show Mon 12/05/2022 12:19 PM. That's it. I don't want the military time or the GMT +0000 stuff in there.
EX:
Release-17
Date : Mon 12/05/2022 12:19:37 PM
Build Number: 20221026.4

Does anyone know how to format the date properly? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Searched forums and have not been able to find any solutions.

Comment: Could you please kindly share the full template?

Comment: @VitaZhang-MSFT That is the full template. I am using the Generate Release Notes Markdown by Richard Fennel. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-XplatGenerateReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the time zone and date format in Generate Release Notes Markdown, you need to add custom Javascript extenstion module in the **Generate Release Notes Markdown task -> Custom Handlebars Extension**.

Here is an example:

**Javascript module**

```
  module.exports = {date_formatter(theDate) {
     
         return theDate.toLocaleString("location");
     }};
```

**Task sample:**

```
- task: XplatGenerateReleaseNotes@3
  displayName: 'Generate Release Notes based on Release Comparison API'
  inputs:
    outputfile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/releasenotes.md'
    templateLocation: InLine
    inlinetemplate: |
     # {{releaseDetails.name}}
     **Date** : {{date_formatter releaseDetails.modifiedOn }}
     **Build Number**: {{buildDetails.buildNumber}}
     {{#forEach workItems}}
     {{#if isFirst}}## Work Items{{/if}}
     - **{{lookup this.fields 'System.WorkItemType'}}** #{{this.id}}
     {{/forEach}}
    replaceFile: true
    customHandlebarsExtensionCode: |
     module.exports = {date_formatter(theDate) {
     
         return theDate.toLocaleString("location");
     }};
```

Refer to this sample: [date_formatter.js](https://github.com/rfennell/AzurePipelines/blob/main/SampleTemplates/XplatGenerateReleaseNotes%20(Node%20based)/Version%203/date_formatter.js)  and [Handlebar Extensions](https://github.com/rfennell/AzurePipelines/wiki/GenerateReleaseNotes---Node-based-Cross-Platform-Task/#handlebar-extensions)